# Python 2.7 Structure using tkinter GUI after button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python. I want to create a structure like C in python / advance level of structure to create in Python.

```
typedef struct{
U16    ID;
S8     Name[64];
U32    ResponseSize;
BOOL   Writeable; 
BOOL     Debug_option;  
}sRD_DATA_BY_ID;
```

Structure definition

```
/* Structure definition for RW PIDs containing ASCII values */
sRD_DATA_BY_ID data_by_IDs[] =
{
0x1111, "TEST1",      24, FALSE, FALSE,

0x1112, "TEST2",      24, FALSE, FALSE,

0x1113, "TEST3",       24, FALSE, FALSE,
};
```

And call the same array "data_by_IDs" in Main.py

In python I have defined structure as below:Please let me know its correct.

```
test = { "1":{"ID":0x1111,"Name":"Test1", "ResponseSize": 24,"Writeable": 0},
     "2":{"ID":0x1112,"Name":"Test2", "ResponseSize": 24,"Writeable": 0},
     "3":{"ID":0x1113,"Name":"Test3","ResponseSize": 24,"Writeable": 0} }
```

Now I want above structure to display in tkinter GUI as below:

```
0x1111 Test1 24 0
0x1112 Test2 24 0
0x1113 Test3 24 0
```

Please let me know How to do

Comment: Define a class?

Comment: Or use a dictionary.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes the person needs to help themselves first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone they know who can help them.  StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Your most recent update seems to ask us to write an output statement for you.  Please follow the posting guidelines: SO is not a tutorial service.  Post the code that you tried to write to solve the task, along with a proper description of the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not strong on homogeneity: most of the agglomeration types (tuple, list, dictionary, etc.) allow the elements to be of different types.  The container you use depends more on the functionality you need, rather than the data you're trying to represent.

For instance, a dictionary would begin with something like

```
{ 
    "ID": 0x1111, 
    "Name": "TEST1",
    "ResponseSize": 24,
    "Writeable: FALSE,
    "Debug_option": FALSE
}
```

... and then you'd make a list of those entries.  You do not *declare* a record structure; you merely define the interface and use your methods to create and access the data in the expected form.

Determine the functionality you need; define your interfaces.  Then build the data to match.

Comment: How can I define multiple structure like above example.

Comment: I've given Where do you need help?  I gave you the general principles.  It sounds like you're asking someone to write code for you.